# How do I clear/replace listbox content from a for next loop in VB?

Tags: vb.net, vba, replace, listbox

I want the listbox to only display the data from the most recent click of the run button, instead of adding to the list every time. Here is what I have:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub RunButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunButton.Click
        Dim EndDecimal As Decimal
        Dim StepDecimal As Decimal

        EndDecimal = Decimal.Parse(EndTextBox.Text)
        StepDecimal = Decimal.Parse(StepTextBox.Text)

        For j As Decimal = 0 To EndDecimal Step StepDecimal
            ListBox1.Items.Add(j)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the list, use `Listbox1.Items.Clear()` at the start of the click method. This will purge all items and only add the new ones to the listbox.